# Call asp.net code-behind method when double clicked on html table

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I would like to ask, if there are any way to init asp PlaceHolder and then call code-behind method to change PlaceHolder content ?

Double click event:

```
$('.testtr').dblclick(function () {
   $('.testtr').not(this).toggleClass('hidden');
   $(this).toggleClass('detail');
   $('.details').toggleClass('hidden')
});
```

And code-behind method:

```
protected void GetTaskDetails(int id)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["local"].ConnectionString;
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from Tasks WHERE ID = @id";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    var title = "";
    var desc = "";


    while (reader.Read())
    {
        title = reader[1].ToString();
        desc = reader[2].ToString();
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<table>");
    sb.Append("<tr>");
    sb.Append("ble ble</tr>");
    sb.Append("</table>");

    TaskDetails.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = sb.ToString() });
}
```

I've added PlaceHolder to aspx site. I want to show/init this PlaceHolder when i double click on table row, then it should be filled with data from `GetTaskDetails` method. I tried to use `OnInit`, but I guess it's not what i need. Can you help me find the way to do this ?

**EDIT:**

I've just created new div with PlaceHolder within it. This is how it looks like:

```
<div class="details">
          <asp:PlaceHolder ID="TaskDetails" runat="server" OnInit="TaskDetails_Init"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</div>
```

`.details` have `display:none` property. Now, when I click twice on table row, div shows PlaceHolder content, but the problem is when I'm trying to show all table rows again (double click on table row hiding all other rows, then shows them if I click again). The content of Placeholder stays and I see it below table. Can i clear it somehow ?

Comment: you need ajax call.

Comment: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx

Comment: @BhubanShrestha Thanks for advices. It seems, I can't do that, because its impossible to access controls from webmethod.